# admin on rest uploading images through rest

Tags: ruby-on-rails, admin-on-rest

everyone, I'm using admin-on-rest for front-end development, back-end i am using Ruby on rails. i want to upload images to cloud. i can able to upload to cloud but i need to send image url to my backend so i can store image url. here is my code.

```
<FlatButton style={styles.button} label="Upload Image" primary  onClick={this.handleClick} />


this.handleClick = () => { 
  window.cloudinary.openUploadWidget({ cloud_name: 'dsaf', upload_preset: 'dsafds',  cropping: 'das', 'tags': 'asdf'},
    function(error, result) {
       return result;
    });
```

};

I am not able to send image-url to back-end. can anyone help me?.

Comment: Have you read the documentation about it ? https://marmelab.com/admin-on-rest/RestClients.html#decorating-your-rest-client-example-of-file-upload

Comment: You need to wrap your restClient for fileHandling.